# How to move an object forward in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there any way to move an object forward in Three.js?

Maybe I should convert the rotation.x,y,z to a vector, and deal with it. But I'm beginner, and I don't have any idea how to do it.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

[Object3D](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D) has some handy methods for that.

```
object.translateZ( 10 );
```

Comment: Thanks. And how to move the camera?

Comment: @eqiproo camera.translateZ( 10 );

Comment: @mrdoob Is it possible to make documentaion for threejs more elaborate?

Comment: There is translateOnAxis now too. Needs a normalized Vector for axis.

Comment: Not to nitpick but I wouldn't consider translateZ()  "moving", but more teleporting. Moving when described with 3D objects usually implies that the object can be seen going a specified direction or manner. This method does change the location of the object though :)

Comment: @Ian Steffy I if you repeat translateZ with small increments at some rate, the object will appear to be moving.

Comment: `translateZ` seems to also be moving down diagonally and not only forward, this doesn't seem to answer the question

Comment: @Displee nope, then there is something else going on. just tested it. translating along an object's z axis will move only in one direction, either positive or negative. maybe your frame of reference is rotated or your camera is at an angle. oh, and also don't get fooled, moving along an axis in 3d space will always give the impression of also moving in a different dimension due to dept of field. so when your camera is slightly higher than the object it will appear as if moving down when flying towards you

Answer (score 8):

Please use above answer of @mrdoob, creator of ThreeJS:

`object.translateZ( delta );`

**===OLD ANSWER===**

A tutorial that worked for older ThreeJS version:
http://www.aerotwist.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-three-js/

```
// set position of YOUR_OBJECT
YOUR_OBJECT.position.x = 10;
YOUR_OBJECT.position.y = 50;
YOUR_OBJECT.position.z = 130;
```

More options:

```
var STEP = 10;
var newCubeMatrix = cube.matrix;        
newCubeMatrix.identity();
//newCubeMatrix.multiplySelf(THREE.Matrix4.rotationYMatrix(cube.rotation.y));
newCubeMatrix.multiplySelf(THREE.Matrix4.translationMatrix(cube.position.x, cube.position.y, cube.position.z + STEP));
cube.updateMatrix();
```

details posted here https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7490/translate-object-in-world-space-usings-its-local-rotation

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not know how to do it :S

Comment: Do you have some snippet to start with? did you try any tutorial yet? Did you check the link? Tell me your concerns?

Comment: I have a red cube in my scene, which is rotated around the x,y and z axist. I would like to use the current direction of the object and move it forward using a specified step value.

Comment: This answer is so old it needs to be taken down.  None of this is correct with the latest ThreeJS

Comment: @Tyguy7 thanks for checking this, it was 6 years ago, lol. Just updated the answer so viewers won't deflect from the truth.

Answer (score 7):

The camera is a point in space.
"Forward" is another point in space.
so you can simply use the coordinates of a second point, and make the camera location closer to the "forward" location.

however, you may also need to turn left and right, which might involve polar coordinates.

adjust these values for your convenience:

```
var scene;
var camera;
var playerDirection = 0;//angles 0 - 2pi
var dVector;
var angularSpeed = 0.01;
var playerSpeed = 0.075;
var playerBackwardsSpeed = playerSpeed * 0.4;
```

this function will initialize the scene:

```
function init(){
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    camera.position.z = 5;

    dVector = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ) ;
    camera.lookAt( dVector );

    animate();

}
```

movement of the player is stopped when the player presses the up key.

```
function key_up(event){
    playerIsMovingForward = 0;
    playerIsMovingBackwards = 0;
    playerIsRotatingLeft = 0;
    playerIsRotatingRight = 0;
    playerGoesUp = 0;
    playerGoesDown = 0;
}
```

when the player is moving, we update the position:

```
function updatePlayer(){
    if(playerIsRotatingLeft){ // rotate left
        playerDirection -= angularSpeed;
    }
    if(playerIsRotatingRight){ // rotate right
        playerDirection += angularSpeed;
    }
    if(playerIsRotatingRight || playerIsRotatingLeft){
        setPlayerDirection();

    }
    if(playerIsMovingForward){ // go forward
        moveForward(playerSpeed);

    }
    if(playerIsMovingBackwards){ // go backwards
        moveForward(-playerBackwardsSpeed);

    }

}
```

We assume by forward you meant "using the WASD keys"

```
function key_down(event){
    var W = 87;
    var S = 83;
    var A = 65;
    var D = 68;
    var minus = 189;
    var plus = 187;

    var k = event.keyCode;
    console.log(k);
    if(k == A){ // rotate left
        playerIsRotatingLeft = 1;
    }
    if(k == D){ // rotate right
        playerIsRotatingRight = 1;
    }
    if(k == W){ // go forward
        playerIsMovingForward = 1;
    }
    if(k == S){ // go back 
        playerIsMovingBackwards = 1;
    }


}
```

player will only move as fast as his browser.
so maybe adjust this code?

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    updatePlayer();



    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

this is the code that moves the camera into the position of the dVector object
and also repositions the direction vector (dVector), so that it is always forward from the camera.

```
function moveForward(speed){
    var delta_x = speed * Math.cos(playerDirection);
    var delta_z = speed * Math.sin(playerDirection);
    var new_x = camera.position.x + delta_x;
    var new_z = camera.position.z + delta_z;
    camera.position.x = new_x;
    camera.position.z = new_z;

    var new_dx = dVector.x + delta_x;
    var new_dz = dVector.z + delta_z;
    dVector.x = new_dx;
    dVector.z = new_dz;
    camera.lookAt( dVector );    

}
```

moving forward usually involves turning left and right, here is some code that does that, it also uses polar coordinates, to move the point in relation to the camera (which is the center of the "circle" by a given amount of degrees (in radians)

```
function setPlayerDirection(){
    //direction changed.
    var delta_x = playerSpeed * Math.cos(playerDirection);
    var delta_z = playerSpeed * Math.sin(playerDirection);

    var new_dx = camera.position.x + delta_x;
    var new_dz = camera.position.z + delta_z;
    dVector.x = new_dx;
    dVector.z = new_dz;
    console.log(dVector);
    camera.lookAt( dVector ); 
}

animate();
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: This is a better approach. One thing to note here is returning after         setPlayerDirection(); call in updatePlayer method will halt the player. Remove the return statement for smooth animation

Comment: I'll try it out and get back with results.

Comment: @HiteshSahu, I removed the return statements, the animation is a lot smoother now, may I ask how you got to that conclusion?

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use Vector3's set method/function.

```
   position.set(x, y, z);
```

Comment: Something to Reflect on.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/set

Comment: This was actually the answer I was looking for because "forward" was not precisely against the Z axis. +1

Comment: The translate methods are just aliases that perform this action--why is this answer being downvoted?

Comment: Ya that made no sense maybe up-vote it back to zero for the sake of common sense.