# Move Forward Relative to Object Rotation in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I've just begun looking at Three.js and have a question regarding object movement. In XNA/ShparDX you can do something like the code below, where the object can be moved forward relative to it's orientation. So if the object is looking down, this will move it down. If it is looking to the right, it would move to the right. A video example of this can be seen [here](http://stevehazen.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/matrix-basics-how-to-step-away-from-storing-an-orientation-as-3-angles/), and is the last video on the page.

```
float speed = 0.15f;
Vector3 velocity = objectMatrix.Forward * speed;
objectMatrix *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(velocity);
```

I have tried the following, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11127627/1138263). It simply did nothing when I pressed the key to trigger it.

```
var STEP = 10;
object.matrixWorld.identity();
object.matrixWorld.multiplySelf(three.Matrix4.translationMatrix(object.position.x, object.position.y, object.position.z + STEP));
object.updateMatrixWorld();
```

I have been unsucessful in replicating this using the members and functions available in Three.js. Can someone show me if it is possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mesh.translateX( delta );
mesh.translateY( delta );
mesh.translateZ( delta );
```

To move forward, use `translateZ( delta )`.

If you are just learning, it is best not to mess with `object.matrix`, unless you really know what you are doing. Set the `position`, `rotation`, and `scale` instead.

Comment: I'm definitely not new to matrices but your answer appears to work eloquently. I'll leave the question open for a bit in case anyone has something better to add but yours is looking like the right answer.