# Three.js Move object forward without translateZ

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

Like in lots of other similar questions, I want to move an object forward in `three.js` based on its rotation. The difference is, I can't use [object.translateZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11143797/7237741). This is because I'm using a physics simulator and it will mess up if I update the object like that. Here is an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97mh5fze/1/) of my problem. Feel free to play around with my fiddle and add your updated version to your answer.

I would like the cube to move forward by updating `mesh.position.x` and `mesh.position.z` based on `mesh.rotation.y`.

To keep in mind, I've sometimes realized that `three.js` rotations are a little weird some times when accessing them using `mesh.rotation.y`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using the mesh.getWorldDirection() to get a direction where you want to move your mesh. Then you can multiply it with a scalar to adjust movement speed.

```
direction = mesh.getWorldDirection();

mesh.position.add(direction.multiplyScalar(moveSpeed));
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k1swrxjr/1/

Good luck!

Comment: Do this instead: `mesh.getWorldDirection( direction );` The method instantiates a new `Vector3` every time it is called, otherwise. See the changes in https://jsfiddle.net/k1swrxjr/6/

Answer (score 0):

To move your mesh simply increment the value of the position in which you want your mesh to go in you animate() function instead of init function, example as follows:

```
function animate() {
        mesh.position.x += 0.1;
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
```

This example code will increase x position of your mesh by 0.1 every time animate() is run.

Comment: I was asking for the object to move in the direction that it is facing in, which I made random for the example