# Increase an object.position.set in a while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, three.js, slice, mesh

How to modify the Z value of an object define by object.position.set(x,y,z) ? I tried to modify the value directly (100+width) but it seems not to work. Any ideas ?

```
  while (newGeo2.faces.length != 0) {                                  


        paveMesh2.position.set(0 , 0, -100+width);
        paveBSP2 = new ThreeBSP(paveMesh2);
        scene.add(paveMesh2);


        newBSP2 = filetBSP.intersect(paveBSP2);
        newGeo2 = newBSP2.toGeometry();


        newMesh2.position.set(50, 50, -50+width);
        scene.add(newMesh2);



     }
```

Comment: schouldn't you get object property first, and than add something to it? like object.position.set(x,y, object.position.z + 100). Just guessing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try get position first by paveMesh2.position.z and than add something to it:

```
paveMesh2.position.set(0 , 0, paveMesh2.position.z + 100);
```

I assume you are trying to perform move, am I right?
Try this:

```
paveMesh2.translateZ(100);
```

[How to move an object forward in Three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127543/how-to-move-an-object-forward-in-three-js)