# Get Direction Vector for entity in A-Frame

Tags: javascript, web, 3d, aframe, direction

I have a box in my A-Frame scene that I want to control with the keyboard. I want W, S, and arrow Up/Down to control forward and backward movement, and I want the A, D, and arrow Left/Right to rotate the box left or right.

I have managed to get the box to move back and forward and to get the box to rotate. The problem is that when the box has rotated, I want to be able to press the forward/backward keys to move it in its new direction, but right now it still moves back and forward in the original direction.

HTML

```
 <a-entity id="rover" geometry="primitive: box" material="color: yellow" position="0 1 -3">
```

JS:

```
var up = false,
    right = false,
    down = false,
    left = false;

document.addEventListener('keydown',press)
function press(e){
  if (e.keyCode === 38 /* up */ || e.keyCode === 87 /* w */ || e.keyCode === 90 /* z */){
    up = true
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 39 /* right */ || e.keyCode === 68 /* d */){
    right = true
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 40 /* down */ || e.keyCode === 83 /* s */){
    down = true
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 37 /* left */ || e.keyCode === 65 /* a */ || e.keyCode === 81 /* q */){
    left = true
  }
}


document.addEventListener('keyup',release)
function release(e){
  if (e.keyCode === 38 /* up */ || e.keyCode === 87 /* w */ || e.keyCode === 90 /* z */){
    up = false
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 39 /* right */ || e.keyCode === 68 /* d */){
    right = false
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 40 /* down */ || e.keyCode === 83 /* s */){
    down = false
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 37 /* left */ || e.keyCode === 65 /* a */ || e.keyCode === 81 /* q */){
    left = false
  }
}


function gameLoop(){
  var rover = document.getElementById('rover');
    var currentPosition = rover.getAttribute('position');
    var currentRotation = rover.getAttribute('rotation');


    var direction = new THREE.Vector3(0, currentRotation.y, currentPosition.z);


  if (up){
  rover.setAttribute("position", {x: 0, y: 1, z: (currentPosition.z - 0.1)});
  }
  if(down){
       rover.setAttribute("position", {x: 0, y: 1, z: (currentPosition.z + 0.1)});
  }
  if(left){
       rover.setAttribute("rotation", {x: 0, y: (currentRotation.y + 1), z: 0});
  }
  if(right){
      rover.setAttribute("rotation", {x: 0, y: (currentRotation.y - 1), z:  0});
  }



requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop)
}
 requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop)
```

I'm trying to get a Direction Vector and use it somehow, but I'm quite stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is you're setting the object's position in world space instead of moving it along its own object space coordinates.

There are several ways to go about this, with the most straightforward being using Object3D's translate method, which moves an object along its normalized axes. Instead of setting attributes try calling

`rover.translateZ(# of units)`

Etc. etc. Also see:

> [How to move an object forward in Three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127543/how-to-move-an-object-forward-in-three-js)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot! Had to convert my entity to an object first to get it to work it seems. `var rover = document.getElementById('rover').object3D;`