# Draw and rotate in different directions in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

Say I got a box in Three.js I want to draw incrementing on different directions. I basically want to draw lines with the rectangle, pointing towards random locations. At the moment Im just incrementing the x causing a line being drawn from left to right. Is it possible to rotate my rectangle causing it to going in different direction without changing my incrementing of x in my update function.

It would indeed be handy if there are some way of just kindo of "rotating the canvas".

Here is my code on codepen
https://codepen.io/haangglide/pen/vYGbQRm

Code:

```
var scene, camera, renderer, material, plane;

init();

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 100;

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true });
    renderer.autoClearColor = false;

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false);
    drawLines();

    update();
}

function drawLines() {
    var col = new THREE.Color(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random());
    material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: col, linewidth: 5 })
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(5, 20, 32);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(plane);
}

function update() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }, 1000 / 60);

    plane.position.x += 1;
    if (plane.position.x > 50) drawLines()
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotate your plane object and use translateX() to move forward instead of using position.x

```
plane.rotation.z = 180
plane.translateX(1)
```

[How to move an object forward in Three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127543/how-to-move-an-object-forward-in-three-js)